# What error is causing Ubuntu to not boot properly?

Tags: boot, nvidia, bios

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 on an Alienware m15 R3 with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 2070 Super. The install goes well after disabling Raid, and I accept all the 3rd party options. After restarting, I am left with these lines:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Cashing mode page found
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-300)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
ucsi_ccg 0-000B: i2c_transfer failed -110
ucsi_ccg 0-000B: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
ucsi_acpi USBC0000:00: failed to reset PPM!
ucsi_acpi USBC0000:00: PMM init failed (-110)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Did that and nothing changed. I also switched off secure boot in kubuntu if that helps. I turned off every setting in my UEFI to see if something would change and it had no impact

Comment: Same problem: [    8.677918] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    8.677921] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    8.677927] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110  seems to me to be something about USB-C devices, maybe try unplugging any USBC devices you have plugged in?  Just guesses at this stage.

Comment: Did this get resolved?